# How to get rid of the debugger referrier portion in Chrome Console?

Tags: google-chrome, brave

All I want to do is to use javascript to copy paste data from console's log

Using Chrome or Brave browsers, whenever I use console.log
it always shows the portion highlighted in the image, how to get rid of it?

[image]

Comment: What's the exact benefit of getting rid of it? Not that you would be able to do so anyways, definitely not in Chrome.

Comment: I often use little javascript to extract text via `console.log` and then copy the data to excel to further do working on it, but these VM.... lines also get copied

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no good solution for this, but there are workarounds. Some of which can be found e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64444083/7264739).

The linked answer by @tapeboy7 recommends adding your own function for logging. Which could be simplified to for example:

```
console.l = (...args) => queueMicrotask(console.log.bind(console, ...args))
```

Then you can use `console.l('test')` to output data/logs without that part.